Sort a 2d array with 1d array in appscript
I want, to sort a 2d array with a 1d array in appscript.
so that the 2D array is in the same order as the 1D array.
There is the link of the google sheet:



Array 1D




a


b


c


d


e


f


g


h


i


j


k


l






Array 2D





b
156


f
68


a
507


c
22


d
430


e
555


g
689


k
62


l
395


i
209


j
745


h
37



I use alphabet for the exemple but in my case is not just letter but full name.
I try the sript of a other post name : "Sort array of objects by arbitrary list in Javascript", but it doesn't work, it just give me back my 2d array with out sorting it.
the script i try:
const objects = spreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("feuille 2").getRange('A;B').getValues()
const order = spreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("feuille 1").getRange('A;A').getValues()


const orderIndex = {}
order.forEach((value, index) => orderIndex[value] = index);

// Sort
objects.sort((a, b) => orderIndex[a.id] - orderIndex[b.id]);

// Log
console.log('orderIndex:', orderIndex);
console.log('objects:', objects);

Edit: Script I tried based on the answer, which didn't work:
function myFunction() {

let objects = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Feuille 7").getRange('D:E').getValues()
let order = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Feuille 7").getRange('A:A').getValues().flat()

/* Create a mapping object `orderIndex`:
*/

let orderIndex = {}
order.forEach((value, index) => orderIndex[value] = index);

// Sort
objects.sort((a, b) => orderIndex[a] - orderIndex[b]) 

// Log
Logger.log("/////////////////////////order////////////////////////////////")
Logger.log(order)
Logger.log("/////////////////////////objects////////////////////////////////")
Logger.log(objects)


SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Feuille 7").getRange('H:I').setValues(objects)
}


order is a 2D array. getValues() always returns a 2D array regardless of the size of the range. flatten it to a 1D array:
const order = spreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("feuille 1").getRange('A:A').getValues().flat()

There's no id attribute in 2D arrays. Remove it and get each inner array's first index and sort based on it:
objects.sort((a, b) => orderIndex[a[0]] - orderIndex[b[0]]);

There's also a typo on getRange calls: It should  be A:B and A:A(colon: -not semicolon; )


myFunction()

function myFunction() {

let objects = [['f',130],['b',5],['c',1]]
let order = ['a','c','b','f']

/* Create a mapping object `orderIndex`:
*/

let orderIndex = {}
order.forEach((value, index) => orderIndex[value] = index);

// Sort
objects.sort((a, b) => orderIndex[a[0]] - orderIndex[b[0]]) 
Logger=console

// Log
Logger.log("/////////////////////////order////////////////////////////////")
Logger.log(orderIndex)
Logger.log("/////////////////////////objects////////////////////////////////")
Logger.log(objects)
}




I don't know if it's my fault but it's doesn't work.

@RomainGapteau Check now...it needs to get it's first index

Sorry, but what do you mean by first index ?

@RomainGapteau Check my answer now... It is edited to show what needs to be changed... [I also added a live snippet showing it works(Click Run snippet)]

oh ok, it's work,
thank you very much for your help.

If that solves your question, consider accepting the answer. See how to accept. @RomainGapteau

@doubleunary I don't think you voted the first revision down.. I believe you tested the first revision and voted on the second revision(..because second revision is an edit and you should be able to retract votes)  I'll make a edit.. In any case, there's no need to delete your answer. I believe it actually clarifies OP's  question better and you are right in saying performance gains by optimizing time complexity rarely matters in sheets context..

The question asks how to sort array into the custom order specified by order. In the general case, where the two arrays may contain a different number of items, that is hard to do with Array.sort(), because that method only lets you compare items in array against each other. The question however specifies that items should be compared and sorted according to order, which is a different array.
One way to sort array into the custom order specified by order is to use Array.map(), like this:
/**
* Sorts a 2D array by the first column to the sequence shown by order.
* Keys that do not appear in order are sorted to the top of the array.
* Doesn't mutate array.
*
* @param {Object[][]} array The 2D array to sort.
* @param {Object[]} order A 1D array that shows how to sort.
* @return {Object[][]} Sorted copy of array.
*/
function sortArrayByOrder_(array, order) {
  const sortIndex = array.map((row, i) => ({ i, index: order.indexOf(row[0]) }));
  sortIndex.sort((a, b) => a.index - b.index);
  return sortIndex.map((m) => array[m.i]);
}

You can use the function like this:
function test(objects, order) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if (!objects) objects = ss.getRange('feuille 2!A1:B').getValues();
  if (!order) order = ss.getRange('feuille 1!A1:A').getValues();
  const sorted = sortArrayByOrder_(objects, order.flat());
  console.log(sorted);
  return sorted;
}

The results will look like this:

Note how the unusual placement of f, e and d is reflected in the result.
See Array.map().

I believe OP's original approach( and subsequently my answer) is faster at O(n)[in best case timsort and in worst case at O(n log n)]. This would be slower because of the nested loop at O(n^2),  which would matter, if the  array is very large - for each n, every n is revisted by filter.

@TheMaster yes... but the performance difference will still be negligible in most any Sheets context. V8 is lightning fast, so the grand majority of the execution time will be spent in initialization, SpreadsheetApp methods and return overhead.

Switched to a mapped sort.

Nice.  I think indexOf does the second loop for every row. But  unlike filter, indexOf would probably stop at the first find rather than iterating fully.. so it's better than O(n^2)

In V8, Array.indexOf() is highly optimized and uses a binary search during subsequent passes (from memory, sorry no reference.)

function myfunk101() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const vs1 = sh1.getRange("A1:B" + sh1.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();
  const vs2 = sh2.getRange("A1:A" + sh2.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();
  vs1.sort((a,b) => {
    let va1 = a[0].localeCompare(b[0])     
    let va2 = 0;
    if(va1 === 0) {
      va2 = a[1].localeCompare(b[1],"en",{numeric:true})
    }
    return va1 + va2
  })
  vs2.sort((a,b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0])) 
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs1).replace(/],/g,'],\n'));
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs2).replace(/],/g,'],\n'));
}

[["a","507"],
["b","156"],
["c","22"],
["d","430"],
["e","555"],
["f","68"],
["g","689"],
["h","37"],
["i","209"],
["j","745"],
["k","62"],
["l","395"]]
[["a"],
["b"],
["c"],
["d"],
["e"],
["f"],
["g"],
["h"],
["i"],
["j"],
["k"],
["l"]]


localeCompare

